# @Resource annotation not injecting a subclass

Tags: spring

The @Resource annotation for a service is not injecting a subclass unless I explicitly include the @Component annotation in the subclass. Is there a way to request a subclass be "wired" with the parent @Resource without requiring annotations in each child class? The way I discovered this was by creating a subclass and failing to include the @Component annotation. I was quickly faced with the dreaded NPE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@Component` annotation works only for the class where it's declared, not for its subclasses (for performance reasons, I guess: otherwise it would require traversing of all ancestors for each class being scanned).

As a workaround, you can declare an `assignable` filter for your parent class in `<context:component-scan>`:

```
<context:component-scan base-package = "...">
    <context:include-filter type = "assignable" expression = "... your parent class ..." />
</context:component-scan>
```

Comment: Thanks brother!  I assume you mean descendants of the parent class?  Also, would this include filter require specifying all classes that might have descendant classes that are not annotated with @Component?  This would be awkward and more difficult than adding the annotation!  I suppose now is a good time to read about context:include-filter.

Comment: @stanlick: I mean that to achieve the desired behaviour Spring should either search all ancestors of each class for `@Component` annotation, or traverse all descendants of `@Component`-annotated class. Startup speed would suffer in both cases. And yes, I meant a separate filter declarations for each parent class, because I can't see any other ways, except for `@Component` at each child class.

Comment: Great explanation!  Yeah, adding (the redundant) @Component results in appropriate injections in child classes but seems to be a little silly.  To me it's like "double" configuration.  If Foo extends Bar and Bar is injected, Foo should be too as a result of Foo BEING-A Bar.